# Writing a simple python script that record all my keyboard and mouse input for games like Genshin Impact

Tags: python, keyboard

So I want to start a project that record my keyboard input and maybe mouse movement for some PC games. I looked arount found some useful python library(like ***keyboard*** and pyautogui) that perform these functions, and it works as I execute the program on my editor window. But when I have my games open, it seems that the program stop recording my inputs. I thint that there might be a security check behind it? This is my first time to try a script, what should I know beforehand to start this project. And any idea why this is happening and how to deal with it?

Comment: This is It is not security. It is because games take charge of the keyboard at the hardware level and `pyautogui` and friends work with OS-level messages. The game intercepts an in-game keystroke and it doesn’t reach the OS. I don't think there is a way to do what you want using any Python library I know of.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a "keylogger". The libraries you have mentioned are for capturing inputs to be used in your own application.

Here's a good article about the subject that teaches how to do this for different operating systems. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-keylogger-in-python/